# How to run a java application from another java application and keep it running after the master program returns?

Tags: java, exec, apacheds

I'm trying to run ApacheDS instance from my java application.
I use such `run()` method of ScriptWrapper class to execute script that is shipped with ApacheDS to run it:

```
public class ScriptWrapper implements Serializable {
    private String scriptPath;

    protected Process run(List<String> params) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("Executing script="+scriptPath);
        params.add(0, scriptPath);

        if(workDir != null) {
            return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params.toArray(new String[params.size()]), envp.toArray(new String[envp.size()]), new File(workDir));
        } else {
            return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params.toArray(new String[params.size()]));
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is, that when tomcat on which this app runs, is terminated and/or ScriptWrapper is garbage collected, the instance of ApacheDS also terminates. How to keep it alive?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers. I've decided to address the problem in different way and daemonized the process with script comming with binary ApacheDS installation.

Comment: problem resolved if yes, please share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your main process should wait for it's children before ending.

The object Process has a method `waitFor()`.  You can create a new thread and then run and wait for any other process.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can prevent your object from being garbage collected by holding reference of the  `ScriptWrapper`.

You can use singleton to hold reference. As your object is referenced actively it won't be collected by GC.

```
public class ScriptWrapper {
  private static ScriptWrapper uniqueInstance;

  private ScriptWrapper () {
    }

  public static synchronized ScriptWrapper getInstance() {
    if (uniqueInstance == null) {
      uniqueInstance = new ScriptWrapper ();
    }
    return uniqInstance;
  }

  protected Process run(List<String> params) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("Executing script="+scriptPath);
        params.add(0, scriptPath);

      if(workDir != null) {
             return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params.toArray(new String[params.size()]), envp.toArray(new String[envp.size()]), new File(workDir));
       } else {
         return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params.toArray(new String[params.size()]));
      }
  }
```

}

Hope this could help you !.

Comment: Java API for Process says: The subprocess is not killed when there are no more references to the Process object, but rather the subprocess continues executing asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

I wonder by calling a shell or the command on windows to exec your command would that work?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "/bin/bash -c yourCommand yourOptions &" ).waitFor();
```

The Bash & (ampersand) is a builtin control operator used to fork processes. From the Bash man page, "If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell".

I am not sure how windows would work out try maybe

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "command.exe yourCommand yourOptions" ).waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows it is like this

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd /c yourCommand yourOptions");
```

you need not put `p.waitFor()`..